# If $f(x)=f(0)+o(x^2)$ for $x \rightarrow 0$, what can we say about $f''(0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let's say that $f(x)=f(0)+o(x^2)$ around $0$ (where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R})$. We have, by definition, that:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t^2}=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}=0=f'(0)$$
So $f'(0)$ exists and is equal to $0$. Now, if $f$ is differentiable at least $2$ times, we have by Taylor that $$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+f''(0)\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$$ and by confronting it with $f(x)=f(0)+o(x^2)$ it follows that $f''(0)=0$. The problem is that we don't know a priori if $f''$ exists in $0$ or not. Can we say something about it? Does it exists? Is it equal to $0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=f(0)+o(x^2)$ ensures that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ with $f'(0) = 0$, but nothing can be concluded about $f'(x)$ in a neighborhood of $x=0$, or about the existence of $f''(0)$.

Functions of form $f(x) = x^m \sin(1/x^n)$ can often be used to show that growth conditions on $f$ do not lead to growth conditions on their derivatives.

As an example, the function
$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^3\sin(\frac1{x^{2}}) & \text{ for } x \ne 0 \,, \\
0  & \text{ for } x = 0 
\end{cases}
$$
satisfies $f(x) = o(x^2)$ for $x \to 0$. It has the derivative
$$
 f'(x) = \begin{cases}
3 \sin{\left( \frac{1}{{{x}^{2}}}\right) } {{x}^{2}}-2 \cos{\left( \frac{1}{{{x}^{2}}}\right) } & \text{ for } x \ne 0 \,, \\
0  & \text{ for } x = 0 
\end{cases}
$$
which is not even continuous at $x=0$, so that $f''(0)$ does not exist.

Another example is $g(x)=x^3\sin(\frac1{x^{3}})$ where $g'$ is unbounded in any neighborhood of $x=0$.